# Umbraco - Have same page in Multiple Menus

Tags: xslt, menu, umbraco

I have a website in Umbraco with multiple menus. Some of the pages are in both menus. What is the best way to create a menu with XSLT (or something else) that can allow then client to easily put content where they want?

Example:

Main Menu
  -Home
  -About Us
      -Terms of Use
      - Services
  -Add New
  -Contact

Side Menu
   - News Story 1
   - News Story 2
   - News Story 3

Footer Menu
   - Careers
   - Terms of Use
   - Contact

My original thought on this was to create 3 separate content folders (one for each menu) but if I do that how does something like Terms of Use or Contact get used by both menus? Would I have to hard code it in?

Answer (score 1):

You need to use either of these options:

1. Let user to select from your root node (Which is not good)
2. Create a Data Type (I suggest use render control as
       UltimatePicker for instance). Then Set parent ID to your root node
       id and in "Document Alias filter" provide the document type aliases
       you want (Comma Separated) to be loaded in your selector and also
       check SHOW GRANDCHILDREN too.
3. Create a new Document Type (i.e. NavLinks) having a label text and
       target page for instance. Then your selector will load all items created under
       this doc type.

Hope that helps.